# Create Camel endpoints in java to use in xml routes

Tags: java, xml, apache-camel

I've been trying to create endpoints in java and have those endpoints referenced in my xml routes but have been unsuccessful. I can do this in xml:

```
<endpoint id="kafkatopic" uri="kafka:..."/>
```

and have the endpoint referenced in the routes:

```
<route id="eventflow">
    <from ref="kafkatopic" ...>
```

What i want to do is replace the xml endpoint declaration using java. I've tried something like:

```
Endpoint kafkaep = camelCtx.getEndpoint(kafkaUri);
```

however i'm stumped on how i can create a key "`kafkatopic`" to refer to the endpoint such that the xml route is able to find it. I've checked the `EndpointRegistry` but doesn't allow me to provide a simple name for the endpoint.
Any help is appreciated. Thanks.

Here's my camelContext:

```
<camelContext xmlns="http://camel.apache.org/schema/blueprint"
    trace="true" id="context">

    <routeBuilder ref="myRouteBuilder" />
    <route id="eventflow">
        <from ref="kafkatopic" ...>
```

My simplified RouteBuilder.configure() has below. Here i was trying to put the endpoint in the endpointRegistry hoping that it will used by the xml route. There's not a lot of docs on EndpointRegistry so i was shooting in the dark with this.

```
    // endpoint i have formatted to be "someKey=uri"
    String endPoint = getConfigs("camel-endpoint");
    String [] eptoks = ep.split("=", 2);
    EndpointRegistry<String> endpointRegistry = camelContext.getEndpointRegistry();
    Endpoint endpoint = camelContext.getEndpoint(eptoks[1]);
    endpointRegistry.put(eptoks[0], endpoint);
```

Comment: Please, give us all your code about this problem

Answer (score 1):

You could try defining the endpoint in Spring, either explicitly:

```
<bean id="kafkaComponent" class="org.apache.camel.component.kafka.KafkaComponent"/>
  <bean id="kafkaEndpoint" class="org.apache.camel.component.kafka.KafkaEndpoint">
    <constructor-arg value="kafka:..."/>
    <constructor-arg ref="kafkaComponent"/>
</bean>
```

or using Spring factory bean and method:
http://www.javabeat.net/create-spring-beans-using-factory-methods/

Comment: But that would force me to create the endpoints statically by declaring them in the spring/blueprint xml. I need a way to create any number based on what's in the configuration.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to achieve this would be to create a class which implements the

```
org.apache.camel.Processor
```

interface and configure this in the spring xml file, e.g.

```
<bean id="sp" class="com.mycompany.SimpleProcessor"/>
```

In your route you can then reference this simply using the id you gave in the bean, e.g.

```
<to uri="sp" />
```

Comment: I need an endpoint and i want to programmatically create one to many endpoints depending on a configuration and use those created endpoints in my routes.

Comment: You can create your own component that creates an endpoint and use that, I use the camel-archetype-component maven archtype which creates a basic component that you can customise - see http://camel.apache.org/creating-a-new-camel-component.html for more information on using this.

Answer (score 0):

I would say that makes it a bit confusing to read although perhaps you have a good reason but when I look at the route I want to clearly know the endpoint details unless they are referenced above somewhere. To have to look up the endpoint in a java class can be cumbersome later on.

I recently found out that you can write your entire RouteBuilder logic in java and simply let the blueprint xml call it just like any other bean? That why your routes are in java and the startup mechanism in xml.

Comment: The endpoints that i intend to create are really "edgepoints" and not intermediate endpoints, i.e., they're connections to external systems that vary depending on the environment and the application, hence my needing to create them from configuration. I'm actually using routebuilder to create the endpoints and loading a route file (outside of the blueprint.xml) into my camelcontext.

Answer (score 0):

I know it's late but here's what i did to make this work. Basically i programmatically created the endpoints simply as "direct" endpoints based on configuration and reference those direct endpoints in my camel routes xml file. That way i avoided having environment specific values like hostnames, port numbers, etc., in my xml routes file and just have one version for all environments.